# Vue JS: filter on API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

below in my code, i have stored user in API JSON and i wanted to get users with `role : Admin` and their `username` only but it didn't work.
below is my JSON body response and code

```html
  "response": [
        {
            "profile_picture": "",
            "verified_by_email": false,
            "_id": "61c3a765c5f55200049de490",
            "username": "user2",
            "email": "user1@yahoo.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$pMOyjwVf1RkaIeVdNKWdaucVRybsDEEN3fjxLZOctJyL42HqrlRgC",
            "role": "User",
            "phone_number": "12365478",
            "createdAt": "2021-12-22T22:32:05.034Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-12-22T22:32:05.034Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "profile_picture": "",
            "verified_by_email": false,
            "_id": "61c325ea02526b000424929f",
            "username": "nina",
            "email": "nin@yahoo.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$steP5Aq9mcTIA8XLjm9Y5ONoWQUMEWLD7TJPSHzTksqbOTpv9MbD.",
            "role": "Admin",
            "phone_number": "123456",
            "createdAt": "2021-12-22T13:19:38.240Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-12-22T13:19:38.240Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
computed:{

getAdmin(){

// i stored my API  respone in array Users

this.Users.filter(users => {
          return users.role;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine a filter and a map to get your desired result.

```js
var users = 
{
"response": [
        {
            
            "_id": "61c3a765de490",
            "username": "user2",
            "email": "user1@yahoo.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$pMOyjwVf1RkaIeVdNKWdaucVRybsDEEN3fjxLZOctJyL42HqrlRgC",
            "role": "User",
            "phone_number": "12365478",

        },
        {
           
            "_id": "61c325e424929f",
            "username": "nina",
            "email": "nina@yahoo.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$steP5Aq9mcTIA8XLjm9Y5ONoWQUMEWLD7TJPSHzTksqbOTpv9MbD.",
            "role": "Admin",
            "phone_number": "123456",
           
        }
    ]
}

// Get all admins
var admins = users['response'].filter((user) => user.role === 'Admin').map((user) => user.username)

console.log(admins)
```

Comment: thank you, but i edited my question ... i wanted to get username with role =Admin

Comment: I made an edit :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return from `getAdmin` and also provide a comparison in filter to test for the Admin role

```js
computed:{
  getAdmin(){
    return this.Users.filter(user =>  user.role === 'Admin')
  }
}
```

Edited based on modified question:

```js
computed:{
  adminNames(){
    return this.Users.filter(user =>  user.role === 'Admin').map(user =>  user.username)
  }
}
```

Edited again based on comments:

If you only expect there to be one Admin user at any given time, you could do this:

```js
computed:{
  adminName(){
    const admin = this.Users.find(user => user.role === 'Admin')
    return admin && admin.username

    // or using optional chaining
    // return this.Users.find(user => user.role === 'Admin')?.username
  }
}
```

Comment: it gave me the name like this ["username"] inside an array :\

Comment: You said you wanted to get users (plural) whose role was Admin, so yes, it will be an array that is returned.

Comment: True but when i use it i need each username to be separated, it's something similar to vue inline html v-for="(admin,index) in adminNames" :key="index" then when showing {{admin}} it gives each one .. i needed that in js not in vue inline html

Comment: Updated @sara97